# How to add the "shutdown applet" back after installing `ubuntu-desktop`

Tags: gnome-panel

I just installed Ubuntu Server then did

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
startx
```

But the desktop is missing the icons/applets on the top right: shutdown, etc. I want the shutdown + network only for now. How do I add it back?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you putting a GUI on Ubuntu Server?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Shauna, I am new at that time to Linux/Ubuntu/Terminal at that time

Comment: If you're looking to use Ubuntu for desktop, you're better off using the desktop version, especially if you're still learning the ropes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package responsible for the buttons in the right upper corner is `indicator-session`. In order to get the buttons displayed, you also need `indicator-applet-complete`. Install these packages it with:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install indicator-applet-complete indicator-session
```

After the installation, you need to re-login in the graphical session.

I've verified this by removing all packages related to the Ubuntu desktop on an Ubuntu 11.04 Live CD and by installing the server using `tasksel`. After that, I did exactly what you did: installing `ubuntu-desktop` by running:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install ubuntu-desktop
```

You should not start X directly through `startx`, rather run `sudo start gdm`.

Answer (score 1):

The package related to this are `indicator-session` and `indicator-applet-session`.

Comment: I've tested it in a VM, it did not work. `indicator-applet-session` is a dependency of `ubuntu-desktop` and `indicator-session` is a recommends for `indicator-applet-session`.